# Manipulate #defined array with preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, undefined

There is the following define somewhere on an SDK:

```
#define MYVECTOR { 0, 1, 2  }
```

However, I need the position 1 of this array to become double of what it is currently defined to be, and for the SDK to use it.

One option would be to undefine and redefine with the values that I wanted.
However, I do not wish to hardcode the the values myself. I want the final value to be double of what is is position 1, independently what what the SDK defines it to be (if it says 1, I want 2; if it becomes 4 I want 8). This is because this value will change in the future on the SDK.

How can I achieve something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into Boost.Preprocessor, its arcane tricks can help you. You won't be able to redefine the macro, but defining a macro with a different name and doubled first value is possible. (Though the syntax has to be changed to something like `#define MYVECTOR (0,1,2)`). But why do you want to do it anyway?

Comment: I need to do it because the SDKs use case does not contemplate my use case, so I need to adapt it.

Isn't i possible to do simply with the C99 pre-processor?

Comment: No this is not possible with only the preprocessor. You can write a C program that uses this preprocessor definition to print another preprocessor definition, and use it in your build process.

Comment: perhaps a `macro-writing macro` would do your trick?

Comment: Boost.Preprocessor is a library. Though I just noticed that the post says you can't change the initial macro definition, so it may be unusable here.

Comment: Do you really want to convert it in preprocessor? Often compilers are smart enough to optimize the code, if you define the constant in the header file.